# Python: counting occurrences of a set of strings in a file

Tags: python, string, count

I have a big text file and am looking for the best way to implement the following:

- define a set of strings where each string looks like "x y", each of x, y is an integer that can take on a number of values.
- look through the file, and locate and count each instance of "x y". Return the result as a list that looks roughly like ("x y": count).

I'm a beginner in programming and Python, and the only thing I can think of is something like

```
f = open('file', 'r')
for x in xrange:
    for y in yrange:
        xystring = str("%i %i") %(x,y)
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            count += line.count(xystring)
        print xystring, count
```

Now my obvious problems are that this looks inelegant even to me, and that it will scale badly - I will ultimately need this method to count all instances of, say 7^7 different strings. I will also need to scan this across multiple files while keeping track of the counts for each string. I am looking for the most efficient and Python-esque way of getting this done.

Thanks!

Comment: Like the `pythonesque` adjective, but we normally use `pythonic`. You could try to use regular expressions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
as for keeping track of multiple string in each of the files a dictionary seems good to me: {'filename1':[list of counts of different strings or a dictionary], 'filename2': [another list or dictionary]}.

Comment: Try to locate pairs with regular expressions — http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: The `for line in f` loop won't work; once all the lines are read in the first iteration of the outer loops, the file iterator is empty. You could move the `for line in f` loop to be the outermost loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
from collections import Counter

pairs = Counter()

with open(...) as fp:
   for line in fp:
      pairs.update(re.findall(r'\d+\s+\d+', line))
```

Comment: this looks promising -  what would be the easiest way to extend this to negative integers also? Something like `\d|-\d` ?

Comment: @user28400: it depends. If the input is `1 -2 3 -4` - how many "pairs" are there?

Comment: I ended up implementing exactly your solution (with -? in the regex to include negative digits). Works like a charm, thank you again.